# Suppose $A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)=B\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)$. If $A$ and $f(k)$ are known, how to find $B$ and $g(n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity, products, infinite-product

My question like "some-to-product" or vice versa.

See the following example (for reference, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80#Proof_1) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product));

$$\pi=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{4(-1)^k}{2k+1}=2\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2+8n+4}{4n^2+8n+3}$$

My question is:

If

$$A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)=B\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)$$

Is there a way/procedure one can use to find out $B$ and $g(n)$ if $A$ and $f(k)$ are given, and $B \ne A$?

So if $A=\pi$ and $f(k)=\frac{4(-1)^k}{2k+1}$, then one can find (using that way, if any) that $B=2$ and $g(n)=\frac{4n^2+8n+4}{4n^2+8n+3}$.

---

***EDIT:***

I know that $g(n)$ will change as $B$ changes. Hence infinitely many combinations of $B$ and $g(n)$ are there. To understand me better, say we choose a real $B$, (then) we find out the (suitble) $g(n)$.

***NOTE:***

Some people commented/answered with defining $g(0)$ and $g(n)$ for $n>=1$ separately!

This is not matching my question above, $\color{red}{A=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)=B\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)}$.

---

Hopefully my question is clear, and hopefully there is a way.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: @metamorphy I missed that. I will edit my post.

Comment: Your question has no answer, you can always construct trivial examples, for example you can take $B=cA$ for any constant $c$ and $g(n)=1\forall~n\geq 1$ and $g(0)=1/c$. I mean, probably you can find interesting formulas for some particular cases, but your question is equivalent to ask how many possible expansions of number as an infinite product can be made, which is infinite. Also, $f$ does not play any role in your question.

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \prod_k{ f(k) } = \exp \left({\sum_k{ \ln{f(k)} }} \right) $.  In other words, for any reasonable sum, you can easily rewrite it as a product and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't uniquely defined. You can take e.g. $B = 1$, $g(0) = A$, $g(i) = 1$ for $i > 0$, or many, many other combinations.

Comment: I know that $g(n)$ will change as $B$ changes. My question is how to find a combination of $B$ and $g(n)$? Also, there is an issue with your answer, which is; you defined $g(0)$ to be $A$, but in my post I am asking about $g(n)$ for $n \in [0,\infty)$. Well, I will edit my post to be clearer.